# capturing image with raspverry pi and camera v3

Tags: image, qt, raspberry-pi, pyqt

I'm trying to capture an image with raspberry pi and camera v3 (wide), but anything seems to work. All provided examples work properly but I cannot manage it to work even I'm following them. No file is generated in the .py program file directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

import select

import libcamera

import time

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,  QWidget, QHBoxLayout)

from picamera2.previews.qt import QGlPicamera2



from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview







# Loop to keep taking photos

picam2 = Picamera2()

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
qpicamera2 = QGlPicamera2(picam2, width=1280, height=720, keep_ar=True)
#qpicamera2.done_signal.connect(callback, type=QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
layout_h = QHBoxLayout()
layout_h.addWidget(qpicamera2, 80)
window.setLayout(layout_h)
window.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")



pic_config = picam2.create_still_configuration(main={"size": (1920, 1080)}, lores={"size": (1280, 720)}, transform=libcamera.Transform(vflip=1), display="lores")

picam2.configure(pic_config)

#window.showFullScreen()

picam2.start()
window.show()
app.exec()

sleep(2)
picam2.capture_file('a.jpg')




#while True:
 #print("A")
```

Comment: The first thing is to ensure the camera is enabled, detected and delivers pictures without any Qt stuff involved https://raspberrytips.com/troubleshooting-camera-module/

Comment: @MarkSetchell the camera is enabled and delivers pictures, the problem comes with Qt...

Comment: Maybe consider adding the `Qt` tag if it is a `Qt` issue.